# How to get attribute value from inside a tinymce listbox control item

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm trying to get the item 'data-id' attribute in onselect event, without luck.

Here my code:

```
    createControl: function (n, cm) {
        switch (n) {
            case 'ColorTextBox':
                var mlb = cm.createListBox('ColorTextBox', {
                    title: 'color texto',
                    onselect: function (v) {
                        var ed = tinymce.activeEditor;
                        ed.formatter.register('custom_format', { inline: 'span', styles: { color: '%value' }, classes: 'color_text', attributes: { 'data-color': '%value' } });
                        ed.formatter.apply('custom_format', { value: v });
                    }
                });

                for (i in CssStyles.colors.text) {
                    mlb.add('color texto #' + i, CssStyles.colors.text[i], attributes = { 'data-id': i });  //-> Is this attribute reachable from onselect event or is there a way?
                }

                return mlb;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved. The way is in through an iterate from the mlb object to get the same attribute data-id as in list item.
Maybe is not the best way, but at the moment, I couldn't find a better one.

Here is the modified code:

```
createControl: function (n, cm) {
    switch (n) {
        case 'ColorTextBox':
            var mlb = cm.createListBox('ColorTextBox', {
                title: 'color texto',
                onselect: function (v) {
                    var ed = tinymce.activeEditor;
                    var id;

                    for (i in mlb.items) {
                        if (mlb.items[i]['data-color'] == v) {
                            id = mlb.items[i]['data-id'];
                        }
                    }

                    ed.formatter.register('custom_format', { inline: 'span', styles: { color: '%value' }, classes: 'colors_text_' + id, attributes: { 'data-index': '%value' } });
                    ed.formatter.apply('custom_format', { value: v });
                }
            });

            for (i in CssStyles.colors.text) {
                mlb.add('color texto #' + i, CssStyles.colors.text[i], attributes = { 'data-id': i, 'data-color': CssStyles.colors.text[i] });
            }

            return mlb;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope to be helpful. Regards.